# Send a struct and an int

Tags: c, mpi

I would like to send a struct and an int via MPI_Bcast. I saw that you can use MPI_pack to pack for example 3 int into one buffer, send it, and after unpack it. Is it possible to do the same for a struct and an int?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it is possible, you can just pack that struct and int inside another struct.

Comment: You can create your type with `MPI_Type_create_struct` [doc](https://www.rookiehpc.com/mpi/docs/mpi_type_create_struct.php). `MPI_pack` have only one argument for type [doc](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Pack.html)

Comment: `MPI_Pack` packs MPI types, not types native to your language. So you'd first have to define an MPI type for your struct. That's too compilcated. Instead pack the int and the components of the struct, and on the receiving side unpack it to an int and the components of another struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.
Finally, I created a type with `MPI_Type_create_struct` and I used `MPI_Pack` after.